Treafik uses fallback wildcard domain instead of defined other domain
So I have two domains: main_long.net and short.link:
I have a wildcard cert for the long domain on the default https entrypoint configured.
And override it with the short one in the container config, jet I get served the default wildcard cert.
I get no errors in the log, it just silently passes.
static traefik.toml

dnsprovide
entrypoint http with redirect
entrypoint https with default wildcard cert

    [certificatesResolvers.pb.acme]
      email = "foo@bar.com"
      storage = "/etc/traefik/porkbun/acme.json"
      # caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    [certificatesResolvers.pb.acme.dnsChallenge]
      provider = "porkbun"
      delayBeforeCheck = 0
      resolvers = ["1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1"]
      disablePropagationCheck = true

    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        asDefault = true
      [entryPoints.https.http]
        middlewares = ["security_headers@file"]
      [entryPoints.https.http.tls]
        certResolver = "pb" # default certresolver so I don't need to specify
    [entryPoints.https.http.tls.domains]
      main = ["*.main.net"]
    [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
      asDefault = false
      [entryPoints.http.http]
        middlewares = ["force_https@file", "security_headers@file"]
      [entryPoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint] # can be overriden with priority if needd
        to = "https"
        scheme = "https"
        permanent = true

dynamic config(provided as file)

to generate the default wildcard cert with provider

    [tls.stores]
    [tls.stores.default.defaultGeneratedCert]
      resolver = "pb" # porkbun
    [tls.stores.default.defaultGeneratedCert.domain]
      main = "main.net"
      sans = ["*.main.net"]

dynamic docker container config

because standard provider and entrypoints are set
onl specify, rule and diffrent domain

    services:
      shlink:
        image: shlinkio/shlink:stable
        container_name: shlink
        command: serve
        environment:
          DEFAULT_DOMAIN: short.link
          IS_HTTPS_ENABLED: true
          # GEOLITE_LICENSE_KEY: xxxx
        networks:
          - traefik
        labels:
          traefik.enable: true
          traefik.http.services.shlink.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
          traefik.http.routers.shlink.tls: true
          traefik.http.routers.shlink.tls.domains[0].main: short.link
          // need to add, because sans needs to be overriden from default
          traefik.http.routers.shlink.tls.domains[0].sans: short.link
          traefik.http.routers.shlink.rule: Host(`short.link`)


What I have tried:

Remove the defaults from the static toml,
restart traefik


Solved:
The problem was not setting the sans domain names:
The problem probably was:

The default cert used: main: long.net, sans: *.long.net (as set in dynamic conf)
Only overriding the main, to short.link but let sans default to *.long.net
Therefor Traefik sees short.link and *.long.net and looks for cert with most priority, which ist *.long.net?
=> so it chooses default cert long.net + *.long.net instead of generating new one


Check maybe the reverse DNS entry? But hey, this isn't about programming, maybe try [sf] for instance?
